# Custom chat box colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chat

I have a chat application which appends messages into an unordered list on a random space on the screen (see example https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9MOb.jpg) .

Right now all the messages appear in front of an orange background. I'm wanting to enable the user to choose between 5 specific background colours by clicking on a small box of that colour.

```
li {

 background: #E99D41;
 font-family:  Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #FFF;
   }
```

I know I need to link those colour boxes to the "li background", but I'm not sure how. Would you use Javascript to perform the function of once the certain colour box is selected, the "li background" changes to that colour? If so how?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery to do so....First we make fiv small divs of colors and give it class of their color name.Then we use Jquery to animate background-clor of li.
here's the code...-----

HTML---

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>choose color</p>
<div class="red" style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:red"></div>
<div class="blue" 
style="width:20px;margin-top:10px;height:20px;background- color:blue">     
</div>
<div class="green" 
style="width:20px;margin-top:10px;height:20px;background- color:green"></div>
<div class="yellow" 
style="width:20px;margin-top:10px;height:20px;background-color:yellow"></div>
<div class="black" 
style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-top:10px;background-color:black"></div>
<ul style="margin-top:20px;background-color:orange">
<li>tea</li>
<li>coffee</li>
<li>star</li>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript----

```
var main=function(){
$(".red").on("click", function() {
$("ul").css("background", "red");
})
$(".blue").on("click", function() {
$("ul").css("background", "blue");
})
$(".green").on("click", function() {
$("ul").css("background", "green");
})
$(".yellow").on("click", function() {
$("ul").css("background", "yellow");
})
$(".black").on("click", function() {
$("ul").css("background", "black");
})
}
$(document).ready(main)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vashuStarPro/av52m29m/  ---Demo

Comment: i think he wants something where color is changed through their respective color options, not dropdown

Comment: I'm wanting it where only the messages submitted after the colour is chosen show up that colour. Previous messages remain the colour that they were once submitted. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use different CSS classes for the colors and change the classes based on the selection made by the user.
For example:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="black">message</li>
    <li class="black">message</li>
    <li class="black">message</li>
    <li class="black">message</li>
    <li class="black">message</li>
</ul>
<input id="red" type="radio" value="red" name="colors" />
<label for="red">red</label>
<input id="blue" type="radio" value="blue" name="colors" />
<label for="blue">blue</label>
<input id="black" type="radio" value="black" name="colors" />
<label for="black">black</label>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    color: white;
}
li.black {
    background-color: black;
}
li.red {
    background-color: red;
}
li.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function () {
    $("li").removeClass("black red blue").addClass($(this).val());
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2b3bex3c/)**